# Why TypeScript doesn't throw "Object is possibly 'undefined'" in the following code?

Tags: typescript, undefined

`a` can be an empty array or `number[]`, but TypeScript is fine with the following code, why is that?

```
const a: [] | number[] = []

console.log(a[0].toString()) //  no error is thrown
```

Comment: Because you have not enabled `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` :-)